# Why aren't symbols loading when attaching to running process?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, remote-debugging, visual-studio-debugging

I've been trying to attach to a process on a remote machine to debug an issue.  I was able to connect but the VS debugger warned that:

> The following module was built either with optimizations enabled or
>   without debug information

Now I checked and there are PDB files in the same location as the assemblies I'm attempting to debug.  I have setup the Release configuration to output debug symbols and have done a rebuild to ensure everything is up to date.  SO I'm stuck on this, why would the debugger not be able to find the PDB files?

To rule out a remote debugger issue I tried to attach to a running process on my dev. machine and received the same exact error.  I checked and the PDB files are all there.  Can anyone think of anything else I can check?